# Spring Batch to Handle Issues arises at RowMapper?

Tags: spring, spring-batch

In `Spring Batch` code, I am reading from `Oracle DB` and loading data into `Postgres DB`. The table `PATIENT_VISIT` has `VisitId` as a `varchar` and only stores `Integer` value. While loading data into `Postgres` I want to change data type to `Integer`. On Stage env, out of `millions` records, only single garbage record found which holds alphanumeric value like `A12345` for `VisitId` and while reading I want to skip it for which I've implemented below code.

The code is breaking at line-3 of PatientVisitRowMapper where aphaNumric value can't be set into Integer and generates error **Fail to convert to internal representation**. How to handle this ?

```
public class PatientVisitRowMapper implements RowMapper<PatientVisit> {

    @Override
    public PatientVisit mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
        PatientVisit patientVisit = new PatientVisit();
        patientVisit.setId(rs.getString("id"));
        patientVisit.setName(rs.getString("name"));
        patientVisit.setVisitId(rs.getInt("patientVisitId"));   //Line-3, unable to map alphaNumeric into String and hence exception        
        ........
        .........
        ........
        return patientVisit;
    }
}
```

Code

```
@Bean("readPatientVisitJob")
@Primary
public Job readPatientVisitJob() {
    return jobBuilderFactory.get("readPatientVisitJob")
            .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
            .start(PatientVisitStepOne())
            .listener(PatientVisitJobListener())
            .build();
}

@Bean
public Step PatientVisitStepOne() {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("PatientVisitStepOne")
            .<PatientVisit, PatientVisit>chunk(5000)
            .reader(PatientVisitReader())
            .processor(PatientVisitProcessor())
            .writer(PatientVisitWriter())
            .faultTolerant()
            .skip(NullPointerException.class)
            .skipLimit(10)
            .build();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You either handle those errors in your row mapper implementation or let them bubble up and they will be thrown by the reader.

I you decide to let them bubble up, you can declare the exception type as skippable and you would be able to handle them using a `org.springframework.batch.core.SkipListener#onSkipInRead(Throwable t)`.